# Javascript - Adding more values to an existing object property via a loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to loop through specific characters within elements of an array and create an object that can hold multiple characters as values for each key in that object. The code below overwrites the values of a key with each loop instead of adding to it. I want the expected output to be:

```
{0: ag,
 1: bh,
 2: ci,
 3: dj,
 4: ek}
```

```
let arr = ['abcde', 'ghijk'];
  let obj = {};
  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      let currElem = arr[i];
      currElem.split('').forEach((currChar, index) => {
        obj[index] = currChar;
      })
  }
  console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is totally fine, except that you need to add (concatenate) the letter in the `forEach`, not assign, so something like:

```
obj[index] = (obj[index] || "") + currChar;
// instead of 
// obj[index] = currChar;
```

An example using `reduce` is this:

```js
let arr = ['abcde', 'ghijk'];
console.log(arr.reduce((acc,e) => {
   e.split('').forEach((l,i) => acc[i] = (acc[i] || "") + l)
   return acc;
},{}))
```

Comment: @Bixar the only part "not usual" is `(acc[i] || "")` that takes `acc[i]` (if it's set), otherwise `""`, the rest is only a string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = ['abcde', 'ghijk'];

let res = arr[0].split('').map((el1, idx) => {
  return el1 + '' + arr[1].split('')[idx]
})

console.log(Object.assign({}, res))
```

Edit:

An even simpler solution:

```js
let arr = ['abcde', 'ghijk'];
let arr1 = arr[0].split('')
let arr2 = arr[1].split('')

let res = arr1.map((el1, idx) => arr1[idx] + arr2[idx])

console.log(Object.assign({}, res))
```